# How to write this conditional statements with ternary operators

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to check if the `usr_name` of user is empty, then get his email and adjust a new variable to it.

So here is the traditional way:

```
if(auth()->user()->usr_name != null){
    $user_input = auth()->user()->usr_name;
}else{
    $user_input = auth()->user()->usr_email;
}
```

Now I want to write this with ternary condition operators, so I tried this:

`$user_input = empty(auth()->user()->usr_name) ? auth()->user()->usr_name : auth()->user()->usr_email;`

But this is wrong, since it returns `null` for `$user_input`.

So what is the correct way of writing this with ternary operators?

Comment: You should do `$user_input = !empty()`. Currently the ternary is saying "if the usr_name is empty, return the null value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user_input = auth()->user()->usr_name ?: auth()->user()->usr_email;
```

[Ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) has a short syntax in PHP. The above code is the same as

```
if (auth()->user()->usr_name) {
    $user_input = auth()->user()->usr_name;
} else {
    $user_input = auth()->user()->usr_email;
}
```

Which is most likely equivalent to your code, considering the non strict `!= null` check.

Answer (score 0):

Tenary operator check the result before "?" and if true returns first pair distinguished with ":" if not return second pair.

```
Let say A = true 
C = A ? 1: 2 ;
```

here C equals to 1

In your example you must changed order of tenary result values

```
$user_input = empty(auth()->user()->usr_name) ?auth()->user()->usr_email : auth()->user()->usr_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have your logic back to front

```
$user_input = empty(auth()->user()->usr_name) ? auth()->user()->usr_email : auth()->user()->usr_name;
```

So to be clear, you are giving priority to usr_name if it is set, otherwise use the usr_email

Note that you could put this in an accessor and then call something like `auth()->user()->identifier` anywhere in your project

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP >= 7.0 you could use the null-coalescing operator to write a really beautiful statement instead.

It would look something like:

```
$user_input = auth()->user()->usr_name ?? auth()->user()->usr_email;
```